# Building a generic Camel/Docker image and apply different Camel routes when container starts

Tags: docker, apache-camel

I've got a requirement to create some impostors/stubs/reflectors (pick your own term...) using Apache Camel. These stubs need to:

- listen to a bunch of IBM MQ queues
- for each queue:
- grab messages off the queue when they appear
- extract info from the message via simple XPath or regex extracts and construct a response via a template
- wait some predefined period
- send the response back on another queue

I'm no Camel expert, but I can work out how to do that much...

However, given there's going to be lots of these stubs and I want to use different subsets of these stubs in different circumstances, I want to build a *generic* Camel Docker image, and apply different sets of stubs to it when I start the Docker container.

If it helps clarify things further, I want to be able to store the stub definitions as *uncompiled* code (e.g. XML, Simple, whatever) in git repos - separate from the Docker image - and have the Docker/Camel container load those stub definitions via either volume mount/s or environment variables. Once the container starts, those stub images will persist till the container is killed off - I don't need to manipulate the stubs except when the container starts.

Key thing is that the Camel/Docker image has to be generic, not pre-built with a specific set of stub definitions.

I can handle the Docker side of things OK - what I can't work out is how to have Camel load the stub definitions when Camel starts (i.e. when the Docker container is created) rather than have the stubs loaded into e.g. a WAR at compile time.

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It can be easy implemented using the following way:

- Camel/Docker image has the main cmd to run camel routes from spring xml (you can use whatever logic you want like camel standalone or spring boot etc.)
- Spring XML file is read from some location which is for example hardcoded inside Docker image (like /app/config.xml for example)
- You will start docker container and map required spring XML file to the /app/config.xml

If you cannot map XML files to the running container then you can implement you own small boot part that will on startup read XML content from some env variable, store it into the temporary file and run same logic for starting spring using file context. In that case, you can run docker container and pass spring XML as an env. variable.